# MarkLogic Taskserver D-node vs E-node

Tags: marklogic

I have two questions:

1. Can taskservers be defined against *both* D-node and E-node groups?
2. If yes, is the purpose of that in the E-nodes to run the scheduled tasks and the one in the D-nodes to run the post commit triggers?

Hope the questions make sense!

Comment: For reference: [D-nodes and E-nodes](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/clustering#id_32617)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1: yes. For instance: you can run scheduled tasks on any host, but they are confined to the group in which they are defined. If you define a scheduled tasks in a 'D-nodes' group, then these would run on D-node hosts.

Answer 2: the notion of E-nodes versus D-nodes is not directly related to task server, but it can be useful to be aware which tasks are running where. You are right about triggers: pre-commit triggers run against the evaluation host (the host that received the HTTP request), post-commit trigger against the data host (the host that hosts the forest to which the data is written). With regard to scheduled tasks, see above.

The main reason to distinguish E and D nodes in a cluster is to allow hosts to be optimized for their particular role (E versus D). D nodes need memory mostly for fast access to indexes, and deal with IO for reading/writing data. They also need plenty disk space for store forest data. E nodes handle incoming requests, and merge data results returned by D nodes. They do little IO, and usually depend more on CPU and memory.

Mind though, this is not something that is easy to get right. MarkLogic has a Performance department dedicated to getting this right for our customers..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Answer 3)  1&2 are correct.  But another way to consider, there no such thing as "E Nodes" and "D Nodes".  All ML nodes in a cluster are identical software and capability. Assigning nodes to groups, and calling them D,E or F,G,H has no intrinsic significance. One common useful model is E/D but it's up to the DBA, Developer, IT dept to configure the hardware, software, networking and application use to realize/implement the model.
The ML server itself doesn't 'know' it's an "E node" any more then the CPU does , it will run whatever it's given to do. - the same in one node or 100 .
Other models can be implemented as appropriate to your needs.